# Publishing .Net core to Azure web services from Visual Studio for Mac is not working

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Publishing .Net core to Azure web services from Visual Studio for Mac is not working.

Tried adding web.config but still publish failed.

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise for Mac (updated on 11-May-2017).

But configuring Deployment options via Git from Azure is perfectly working.

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, but was wondering if you could and if someone has gotten it to work

Answer (score 1):

I created new visual studio solution and add ONLY .net core projects.

Tried publishing into Azure and hooray! - its all good now.